# How to export a list into different columns of a csv file?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to find out how to export the following list into a .csv file, matching the certain columns.

`[{'amount': '100', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mælkechokolade'}, {'amount': '20', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mini marshmallows'}, {'amount': '40', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'saltede peanuts'}]`

The above is a result of parsing through a string and using regex to match the contents to their correct header.

`r = re.compile(r"(?P<amount>\d+)\s+(?P<unit>\w+.)\s+(?P<ingredient>.+?(?=<))")
print([m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(s)])`

Is there any way exporting that list properly using .writerow? I was not able to get it working so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to take your data structure and write it to a csv:

```py
import pandas as pd

somedata = [{'amount': '100', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mælkechokolade'}, {'amount': '20', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mini marshmallows'}, {'amount': '40', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'saltede peanuts'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(somedata)

with open("somefile.csv", 'w') as fh:
    df.to_csv(fh)
```

Though `pandas` needs to be pip installed (`pip install pandas`). Otherwise you can just use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module:

```py
import csv

somedata = [{'amount': '100', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mælkechokolade'}, {'amount': '20', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mini marshmallows'}, {'amount': '40', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'saltede peanuts'}]

# This will keep order consistent
headers = [k for k in somedata[0].keys())
new_data = [[rec.get(header) for header in headers] for rec in somedata]

with open('somefile.csv', 'w') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in new_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Which will result in

```
amount,unit,ingredient
100,g.,mælkechokolade
20,g.,mini marshmallows
40,g.,saltede peanuts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_csv function of the pandas DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd

d = [{'amount': '100', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mælkechokolade'}, {'amount': '20', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mini marshmallows'}, {'amount': '40', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'saltede peanuts'}]
pd.DataFrame(d).to_csv('ala.csv')
```